# Java riddle: need a stable random that persistes in a JVM but is different in another JVM

Tags: java, random, jvm

I need to find a way to obtain from the JVM a (somewhat) random string or number that I don't have to store.  But I will need it multiple times over the life of a JVM, so subsequent calls to this method must return the same value. Further, after the JVM is restarted, the same code must yield a different, but still stable value.  The quality of randomness is not important, so long as it's sufficiently hard to guess.

Comment: This problem would be easy if you could store a value in a static field.

Comment: I assume you mean that this *random* value should be different for each `java YourClass` call.

Answer (score 5):

Just seed the Random differently in the different VMs.

```
public class MyClass {
     private int myStableRandomValue = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() ).nextInt();
     ...
}
```

**EDIT**:

If you *really* don't want to store the value, you could seed the Random method above with the process ID, and call it every time the value is requested -- *if* potential attackers do not have access to the process ID.

```
     private int getMyStableRandomValue() { 
        return new Random( getProcessID() ).nextInt();
     }
```

Comment: It will not guarantee the repeated result in the same JVM.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't finished typing yet. If the OP wants a single stable random value, the code above will suffice. If the OP wants a repeatable set of random values, the seed can be stored.

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer - Please re-read OP's post. S/he wants: (1) a value that will be the same over the life of a current JVM and different for different JVMs; (2) s/he does not want to store such value.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman - To the best of my understanding, `Math.Random()` does not guarantee the same result each time the same seed is used.

Comment: @PM77-1 so this method should return a *static* value per JVM? How do you plan doing such thing?

Comment: The answer is off the mark.  I didn't ask how to get a different value from random.  That's easy and indeed doesn't require a lot of thinking.  The problem, as I explained is that I need a stable random and I can't store anything.

Comment: @PM77-1. Thanks for noting the no-store request. But: "If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and return identical sequences of numbers."

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza - If I knew the answer, I would've posted it by now.  I was thinking along the lines of creating an Object and then using its native `toString()` method, but it probably possible that JVM could use the same memory address on another invocation.

Comment: @Forelight - See my edit for one way to do it without storing anything. It doesn't store anything, but it's YAKY-level security if attackers have access to process IDs.

Comment: @PM77-1 but then you would need to *store* the object somewhere, don't you? :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza - Yes. If OP can't really store `anything` and not just this `special value`, then we have a real challenge here.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer - This is clever.  Let me explain what I am after here.  I am working on a general solution to the following problem: how to store sensitive information in memory securely.  The security concern I have in mind is the one commonly known as Malicious Insider. In other words I need to come up with a way to store say passwords or credit card numbers in memory that an insider cannot crack.  Even if he is able to get a memory dump and has access to the production OS.  If I could obtain a stable random that persists for the life of JVM, I can encrypt my sensitive strings with it.

Comment: ... continued. That's why using the PID isn't great because the malicious insider will be able to obtain that from the OS and recover the random value and hence decrypt all the sensitive data.  Hope this makes sense.  Incidentally, .NET has SecureString exactly for this purpose.  But Java doesn't!

Comment: @Forelight - Thanks for providing more detail. Had guessed some of it. So ... if you can't store anything at all in the VM or on the machine on which it's running -- how would you feel about storing something on a secure machine to which each VM could open a connected socket, if fault-tolerance could be addressed? (Also, does .Net store *something* to decrypt its SecureStrings?)

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer SecureString in .NET encrypts the string and although the algorithm is well known, the key isn't and cannot be obtained from the memory dump.  The idea of using another server prob. isn't great for the use case: if the bad guy can get to the prod app system, he prob. can get to the secure server as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Look into the methods of [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html). For example you could do:

```
RuntimeMXBean rmxb = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean(); 
String jvmId = rmxb.getVmName() + "-" + rmxb.getStartTime();
// use jvmId.intern().hashCode() as seed for a RNG
```

As emroy pointed out, it is possible that two JVMs get started at the same time. I suggest concatenating the machine's MAC address to the `jvmId` if this a concern:

```
InetAddress localHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
NetworkInterface networkInterface = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(localHost);
byte[] macAddress = networkInterface.getHardwareAddress();
jvmId += "-" + Arrays.toString(macAddress);
```

Comment: I believe this answer satisfies OP's requirements.

Comment: @PM77-1 Actually if you look at the extended comments, I do not think this answer satisfies requirements (nor does mine).  I suspect there is no solution.

Comment: @emroy - you are right: it is theoretically possible that two JVMs get started at the same time. I realize now, that this problem is very similar to getting a Globally Unique ID. I will add the MAC address to my solution.

Comment: @Tilo - This is the best answer so far.  MAC address doesn't add anything for my use case: malicious insider also has access to that. The start time millis is a good approximation: persists for the life of the JVM and reasonably hard to guess. It's possible to obtain the JVM proc start time from the os, but that typically is second-grained so the bad guy still has to guess over a wide range of values.

Comment: @Tilo I actually like this answer much better than mine, but I don't think it is necessary to get two JVMs started at the same time.  The "Malicious Insider" that Forelight is fretting over could know exactly when the JVM started and reset the clock to that value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the hashCode of a lazily initiated static object.  The below code does not seem to work.  I would guess SAXParserFactory is not in fact lazily initiated.

```
class One
{
     public static void main ( String [ ] args )
     {
    while(Math.random()<0.99){
        new Object();
    }
    System.out.println(javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance().hashCode());
     }
}
```

Comment: `The below code does not seem to work.`  Shouldn't we er, delete the code / answer then? :-)

Comment: The idea of using a lazily initialized object is a good idea, even if the code doesn't work. It might be useful for people with similar questions who look at this answer, and should therefore not be deleted.

Comment: @GregKopff the code is just for reference.  If one is sufficiently interested (I am not one), one can find a suitable lazily instantiated singleton object.